# postfix pcre conditional REPLACE

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix, pcre

I need to modify the "From:" header line in incoming e-mail messages only if "Message-Id:" starts with a defined string. So in main.cf I put:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and header_checks file contains:

```
if /^Message-Id: <footext.+/
/^From: (.*)@johndoe.com/ REPLACE From: ${1}@ext.johndoe.com
endif
```

It doesn't work, the condition does not take. What am I missing?

Comment: Finally I managed to do the same kind of job by a simply Python script: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389323/forward-email-but-change-the-from-address

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

> if /pattern/flags
>
> ```
>    endif  Match the input string against the patterns between
>           if  and endif, if and only if ----> the same <----- input string
>           also matches /pattern/.
> ```

you can not use an if/endif block to match a different header.

Comment: So it seems header_checks is no good to my needs, isn't it? Can you suggest a way to have a conditional replace among header fields (matching a different header line)? Thanks in advance for any help you will offer.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simple way to do this with postfix internal features. For this kind of stuff, I usually attach a content filter  like [FuGlu](http://www.fuglu.org)  (disclaimer: written by me)

Comment: Couldn't find the quote in the link anymore. So it seems this syntax would work in the newer versions of postfix?!?

Comment: No, the restriction is the same like before, things have only been rephrased: `[...]then match **that input string** against the patterns between if and endif.`

Comment: There's an additional section in the docs making that clear as well: `Many people overlook the main limitations  of  header  and  body_checks rules.` `These  rules  operate  on one logical message header or one body line at a time. A decision made for one line is not carried over to the next line.`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post and thought to update since I had a similar issue:
I took a different approach using [postfix pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) as suggested in some of these resources:

- https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail
- http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Conditional-sender-rewrite-based-on-recipient-address-td93497.html

and just because I ran into the issue of loops:

- [Specifying a Postfix Instance to send outbound email](https://serverfault.com/questions/599140/specifying-a-postfix-instance-to-send-outbound-email)
- http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html