# Specifying a Postfix Instance to send outbound email

Tags: postfix, centos6, outboundrules

I have a CentOS 6.5 server running Postfix 2.6x (the default distribution) with five public IPv4 IPs bound to it.  Each IP has DNS and rDNS set separately. Each uses a different hostname at a different domain.  I have five Postfix instances, one bound to each IP, like this example:

- 192.168.34.104   red.example.com       /etc/postfix
- 192.168.36.48    green.example.net     /etc/postfix-green
- 192.168.36.49    pink.example.org      /etc/postfix-pink
- 192.168.36.50    orange.example.info   /etc/postfix-orange
- 192.168.36.51    blue.example.us       /etc/postfix-blue

I've tested each IP by telneting to port 25. Postfix answers and banners properly with the correct hostname.  Email is received on all of these instances with no problems and is routed to the correct place.  This setup, minus the final instance, has existed for a couple of years and works.

I never bothered to set up outbound email to go through any but the main instance, however; there was no need.  Now I need to send email from blue.example.us that actually leaves from that interface and IP, such that the Received headers show blue.example.us as the sending mailhost, so that SPF and DKIM validate, etc etc.

The email that will be sent from blue.example.com is a feedback loop sent by a single shell account on the server (account5), an account that is dedicated to sending this email.  The account receives the feedback loop emails from servers on other networks, saves the bodies of those emails, and then generates a new outbound email header, appends the saved body, and sends the email. It's sending by piping each email to `sendmail -oi -t`. We're doing it this way to mask the identities of the initial servers.  The procmail script that processes these emails works correctly.

However, I *cannot* configure this account to send email through the proper Postfix instance/IP/interface.  The exact same account and script sends email through the main Postfix instance /etc/postfix without any issues.  When I change MAIL_CONFIG to point to /etc/postfix-blue in either .bash_profile or the Procmail script that handles this email, though, I get this error:

```
sendmail: fatal: User account5(###) is not allowed to submit mail
```

I've read the manuals on Postfix.org, searched Google, and tried the suggestions in three previous answers here on ServerFault.com:

[Postfix - specify interface to deliver outbound mail on](https://serverfault.com/questions/234487/postfix-specify-interface-to-deliver-outbound-mail-on)

[Postfix user is not allowed to submit mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/593871/postfix-user-is-not-allowed-to-submit-mail)

[Postfix rejects php mails](https://serverfault.com/questions/574911/postfix-rejects-php-mails)

I have been careful to stop and restart Postfix after each configuration change, and tested the results.  Nothing has worked.  The main postfix instance happily accepts outbound email from account5.  The postfix-blue instance continues to reject email from account5 with the sendmail error above.

As tempting as it is to blame machine hostility, I know that I must be missing something or doing something wrong.  Does anybody have any suggestions as to what it might be?  Please feel free to ask for further information about my setup if you need it.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

At the request of the responder, here are main.cf and master.cf for a) the main postfix instance ("red.example.com") and b) the FBL instance ("blue.example.us")

[NOTE: All parameters not specified below were left at the default  Postfix 2.6 settings]

### MAIN:

**master.cf**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

**main.cf**

```
myhostname = red.example.com
mydomain = example.com
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
inet_protocols = all
lmtp_host_lookup = native
smtp_host_lookup = native
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
local_recipient_maps =
mynetworks = 192.168.34.104/32
relay_domains = example.com,
            example.info,
            example.net,
            example.org,
            example.us
relayhost = [192.168.34.102] # Separate physical server, main mailserver.
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
multi_instance_wrapper = ${command_directory}/postmulti -p --
multi_instance_enable = yes
multi_instance_directories = /etc/postfix-green /etc/postfix-pink /etc/postfix-orange /etc/postfix-blue
```

### FBL:

**master.cf**

```
184.173.119.103:25      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

**main.cf**

```
myhostname = blue.example.us
mydomain = blue.example.us <= Deliberately set to subdomain only.
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
lmtp_host_lookup = native
smtp_host_lookup = native
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
mydestination = $myhostname
local_recipient_maps  = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps $virtual_alias_maps
mynetworks = 192.168.36.51/32, 192.168.35.20/31 <= Second IP is backup MX servers
relay_domains = $mydestination
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix-blue/canonical
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix-fbl/virtual
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/postfix-blue/canonical
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/postfix-blue/canonical
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION" DEFAULT=$HOME/Mail/ MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
authorized_submit_users = 
multi_instance_name = postfix-blue
multi_instance_enable = yes
```

** Additional Information after testing Masegaloeh's latest suggestion **

I just tried adding "account5" to authorized_submit_users, and setting MAIL_CONFIG in .bash_profile for the "account5" shell account, with "export MAIL_CONFIG" also set.  Procmail no longer complains; it thinks that it is properly generating and sending the FBL.  However, maillog reports the following:

```
May 29 14:47:42 newton postfix-blue/qmgr[3522]: 5BC773E612F: from=<fbl@blue.example.us>, size=1106, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 29 14:47:42 newton postfix-blue/qmgr[3522]: warning: connect to transport private/smtp: Connection refused
May 29 14:47:42 newton postfix-blue/error[3766]: 5BC773E612F: to=<fbl-test@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Do I need to add something to a transport configuration file, perhaps?

Comment: These secondary postfix instances, are they using different `main.cf|master.cf` configurations? Can you post the first one and the blue one?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  That's why I mentioned the separate postfix directories, and that I'd checked by telneting to the IPs.  I'll happily provide the files you ask about, but this comment window does not appear to have space.  It's limited to about 500 characters.  How should I do this?

Comment: @CatherineJefferson, you can edit your post and add the config there. By the way, did you mean `account5` is sending via submission instead doing smtp transaction?

Comment: It's sending by piping each email to "sendmail -oi -t".  I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send email via local submission a.k.a `sendmail` it will use default instance e.g. **red.example.com**. This behavior was explained in [postfix official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html#default).

> One Postfix instance is special: this is the instance whose
>   configuration directory is the default one compiled into the Postfix
>   utilities. The location of the default configuration directory is
>   typically /etc/postfix, and can be queried via the "postconf -d
>   config_directory" command. We call the instance with this
>   configuration directory the "default instance".
>
> The default instance is responsible for local mail submission. The
>   setgid postdrop(1) utility is used by the sendmail(1) local submission
>   program to spool messages into the maildrop sub-directory of the queue
>   directory of the default instance.
>
> Even in the rare case when "sendmail -C" is used to submit local mail
>   into a non-default Postfix instance, for security reasons, postdrop(1)
>   will consult the default main.cf file to check the validity of the
>   requested non-default configuration directory.
>
> So, while in most other respects, all instances are equal, the default
>   instance is "more equal than others". You may choose to create
>   additional instances, but you must have at least the default instance,
>   with its configuration directory in the default compiled-in location.

Some suggestions:

1. Based on above snippet, you could try to use `sendmail -C` to specify the instance to submit email. Or
2. The other workaround is swap the the instance, e.g. **red.example.com** become  **blue.example.us** and vice versa.

### Edit based on comments below

```
sendmail: fatal: User account5(###) is not allowed to submit mail
```

The error above caused by `authorized_submit_users` parameter is blank (postfix-blue instance). The effect is nobody could execute `sendmail` via postfix-blue instance. Adding `account5` to that parameter should solves the problem.

Another error

```
warning: connect to transport private/smtp: Connection refused
```

was caused by missing *smtp transport* in **master.cf**. Make sure this line present in master.cf

```
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
```

and add **-o smtp_bind_address=192.168.36.51** at the end of the line so email will send through address 192.168.36.51.

Comment: Unfortunately "sendmail -C" does not work -- I get the same error as with changing the MAIL_CONFIG directory.  (I'd tried that, but didn't mention it earlier.)  Swapping the instances would definitely not work; I don't want to mix the feedback loop with the rest of my mail streams.  Is there a setting in the default main.cf file that would add the other config directory to the "allowed" list?

Comment: What do you mean allowed list?

Comment: @masegaloeh she means this: http://serverfault.com/questions/574911/postfix-rejects-php-mails

Comment: @NickW if that is the case then OP can modify `authorized_submit_users` become `account5`

Comment: She's saying she's done that.. at least as far as I understand.

Comment: In her `postfix-blue` main.cf, the parameter `authorized_submit_users` is empty.

Comment: I have try this scenario (e.g. `authorized_submit_users` is set to `someuser` and set `MAIL_CONFIG` to other instance) in my own box (with postfix multi instances too) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Does it work to send outgoing email from that instance and IP, masegaloeh?  I tried adding account5 for authorized_submit_users, and setting MAIL_CONFIG, and also submitting directly to the proper instance by using sendmail -C /etc/postfix-blue.  I am not sure that I got the proper combination in place, though. I am testing that now, will add the results by editing the main post.

Comment: Do you have line like `smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp` in your master.cf of postfix-blue?

Comment: Yes, currently commented out, and replaced by this:   184.173.119.103:25      unix  n       -       n       -       -       smtp 
  -o smtp_bind_address=184.173.119.103

Comment: Any reason why you have commented that line? Looks like your `sendmail` message use default_transport `smtp` instead `184.173.119.103:25`.

Comment: I commented it out because I want it to use 184.173.119.103:25.  Is it possible to redefine default_transport to that IP for this instance only?

Comment: (1) The entry `184.173.119.103:25` was invalid because it is a smtp not a smtpd (I tried in my box too). The common name is set without **:**. See [this manual](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) and [this example](http://linuxnet.ca/postfix/dedicated_transport.html). If you want to binds `184.173.119.103` for IP address, uncomment `smtp` entry and add `-o smtp_bind_address=184.173.119.103` at the end of the line.

Comment: Yee-HAW!  I uncommented the smtp unix line, and added -o smtp_bind_address=192.168.36.51 and IT WORKS! IT WORKS IT WORKS IT WORKS! <G>  Masegaloeh, I owe you and some other folks here a ${BEVERAGE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE} if we're ever at the same conference.  Thank you!